# Any idea why the custom nav bar back button image isn't displaying with this code?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

Any idea why the custom nav bar back button image isn't displaying with this code?

instead of showing the uiimage it's showing the "< Back" default iOS button in text only

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"freccia.png"] landscapeImagePhone:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(backBtnPress)];
```

could it be this parameter? `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code:

```
UIImage *imageBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnBack.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageBack.size.width, imageBack.size.height);
[btnBack setBackgroundImage:imageBack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonBack;

-(void)back {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: For greater convenience, use this code in a UIViewController category, so you can call it for any view.

Answer (score 1):

You usually set the back button in the parent view controller. However, it might just be easier to use `leftBarButtonItem` instead of `backBarButtonItem`.

Comment: oh, I have some views where it has to be hidden and others where it needs to be displayed

Comment: In that case, I would try moving that code statement to the presenting view controller. If that doesn't work, another alternative is to just set `leftBarButtonItem` to nil in `viewWillDisappear` and reinitialize the button whenever it needs to appear.

Comment: that's what I had at first but there was a noticeable lag with the leftBarButtonItem whereas with backBarButtonItem is immediate. Is it not possible to set a custom image to the backBarButtonItem? It has the initWithImage: option. thanks!

Comment: If you're calling the above code in `viewWillAppear`, try adding `[[self navigationItem] setHidesBackButton:YES];` to it. That should stop the view from trying to render the original back button before displaying the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem by two ways
1. use leftBarButtonItem instead of backBarButtonItem
2. try the below code

```
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```